# Is there any R package for producing marginal effects plots from interaction terms in spatial models? (Using spdep::lagsarlm)

Tags: r, graph, spatial, marginal-effects, spdep

There are several easy and efficient R packages and functions to produce conditional effects plots (marginal effects) for linear regression models, such as `interplot` (Solt and Hu 2021), `ggeffects` (Lüdecke 2018), and `JKmisc/ggintfun.R` (Karreth 2017). However, I could not find any package or function to produce marginal effects graphs for spatial models. In particular, I am conducting a SAR model using the command `lagsarlm` from the package `spdep`.

Consider, for example, the SAR model specification below:

Y = B1X1 + B2X2 + B3X3 + B4X1*X2 + B5X3*X2 + pWy

In this example, I would like to produce two marginal effects plots according to the interaction terms:

1. The conditional effect of X1 on Y when X2 is increasing.
2. The conditional effect of X3 on Y when X2 is increasing.

Is there any way to produce these graphs in R from the results generated using the command `lagsarlm` (package `spdep`)?

Comment: FWIW, I do not think that such a package exists. Of course, I don't know all the `R` packages, but I am the [`marginaleffects` package developer](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) and I know the field reasonably well.

Comment: Thank you, Vincent! I will probably calculate the marginal effects by hand and then plot it using `ggplot2`. I will add the answer here when I am done.